# matplotlib not honoring zorder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've reviewed a number of posts (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726391/matplotlib-draw-grid-lines-behind-other-graph-elements)) discussing `zorder`, and based on the responses I perused, it seems like the following small reproducible example should not be drawing the grid on top of the bar.  Or in other words, shouldn't the fact that the gridlines are assigned to `ax2`, which has a lower zorder number, make it so they are drawn below the bar and the triangle?  How does one force the gridlines to be below everything else?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
pts = ax1.plot(1, 1, 'r^', label='Stream Flow')
ax1.set_zorder(4)
ax1.set_facecolor('none')
ax1.set_xlim([0, 3])
ax1.set_ylim([0, 3])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_xlim([0, 3])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 30])
bar = ax2.bar(1, 15, align='center', color='b', width=0.1, label='Some other value')
ax2.set_zorder(2)
ax2.set_ylabel(r'Other value', rotation=270, labelpad=15)
lns = pts + [bar]
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
leg = ax2.legend(lns, labs, loc='lower right', frameon=True)
leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)
ax2.yaxis.grid(color='silver', zorder=1)

# Following two lines were experiments that failed
#fig.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()-1)
#fig.patch.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Here's what I'm seeing, the gridlines are plotted over the bar (bad) but below the triangle (good).
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas bar plot with secondary y-axis: hide grid line below plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717935/pandas-bar-plot-with-secondary-y-axis-hide-grid-line-below-plot)

Comment: `ax2.set_axisbelow(True)` does the trick for me.

Comment: @BigBen Yep, that worked.  I had tried that in an earlier permutation, but I think it was when I was drawing the grid with the ax1 object.

Comment: Note that zorder only works between elements drawn on the same ax. In this case, everything belonging to ax2 is always drawn on top of everything belonging to ax1, including the grid lines. With `ax2.set_zorder()` you can change the zorder of the axes.  `set_axisbelow(True)` will put the gridlines below the other elements drawn.